# What is system.globalization And what's the difference between it and localization

Tags: asp.net, globalization

and to spice things a bit , what is the best approach for globalization in Asp.net Mvc App

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Globalization** is about producing a map from strings or identifiers to translations in other languages, while **Localization** is about using that map to find the correct translation.  Globalization happens during development, localization happens at runtime.

I'm not very experienced doing this with ASP.NET, but...

As for *how*, the most common approach I see is to have a dictionary per language per assembly (or per UI component), where the values are localized strings.  The keys are typically readonly members on a static class or enum.  There is often a convenience class whose members *are* the map from identifiers to localized messages.

The dictionaries are typically stored in separate files and in a format targeted to human translators.

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478974.aspx

Answer (score 4):

From the [W3C I18n FAQ](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n):

> Localization refers to the adaptation of a product, application or document content to meet the language, cultural and other requirements of a specific target market (a "locale").
>
> Internationalization (or globalization) is the design and development of a product, application or document content that enables easy localization for target audiences that vary in culture, region, or language.

I've never globalized an ASP.NET MVC application, so sorry if I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

> The **System.Globalization** namespace
>   contains classes that define
>   culture-related information, including
>   the language, the country/region, the
>   calendars in use, the format patterns
>   for dates, currency, and numbers, and
>   the sort order for strings.

As for what's the difference between it and localization?  I guess that can be explained as the difference between a car and a city.  One is a destination and the other is how you get there.

I haven't used ASP.NET MVC, but I have used Monorail which is similar.  If I wanted to localize a MR app, I would probably use a separate tree of view files. So while, for english-only, I'd have:

```
\Views\Home\*.asp
\Views\Admin\*.asp
\Views\Products\*.asp
```

for an internationalized app, I'd have something like:

```
\en\Views\Home\*.asp
\en\Views\Admin\*.asp
\en\Views\Products\*.asp
\de\Views\Home\*.asp
\de\Views\Admin\*.asp
\de\Views\Products\*.asp
\es\Views\Home\*.asp
\es\Views\Admin\*.asp
\es\Views\Products\*.asp
```