# What is different between Globalization and Localization in .net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, localization, globalization

I try to find out what basic different between Globalization and Localization? but not find some proper different

i refer this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292205(v=vs.71).aspx

if any one know proper different please explain here.

why they give two different folder App_GlobalResources and App_LocalResources in VS2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is system.globalization And what's the difference between it and localization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278136/what-is-system-globalization-and-whats-the-difference-between-it-and-localizatio)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your link explains it, isn't it?

> "Globalization is the process of designing and developing a software product that functions in multiple cultures/locales."
>
> "Localization is the process of adapting a globalized application, which you have already processed for localizability, to a particular culture/locale."

And GlobalResources and LocalResources is a different concept. LocalResources folder contains resources which apply for one page or user control only. While resources in GlobalResources are accessible in the whole application. Refer to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

**Globalization**

Adapting applications for different cultures: for example

- displaying numbers differently
- displaying dates differently
- collecting user-facing text from resource files, rather than hard-coding them
- allowing UI to work with right-to-left languages

**Localization**

Adapting an application for a specific locale/language: for example, translating into French, or, more specifically, Canadian French.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about difference between Localization (L10n) and Globalization (G11n) or why there are two different resource folders?

The first question could be answered as: G11n consist of L10n and Internationalization (i18n). Localization is an adaptation for different markets (usually consist of translating texts, graphics, colors and modifying UI so that these changes look right), whereas i18n usually regards to enabling Localization (externalizing strings, graphics, allowing different date, time, number, currency, etc. formats, adopting sorting order to specific language, etc.). As I said, G11n is both L10n and i18n.

Why they created two folders? Because sometimes the resource (be it string, graphic, color code) is common for all web pages. In such case you need some kind of Global resources (this name has nothing to do with Globalization, it was meant to indicate application-wide resources).
However, if the resource is specific for given web page, you don't want to mess-up the Global resource folder, it would create a mess. And also, Global resources need to be qualified so that the web page know where to get it from. To make your life easier, somebody created a concept of Local (as a web site specific, not Localized (they all are)) resources. By applying correct naming convention you could access Local resources much easier...

Answer (score 2):

I've always held that the basic definition should be: *Globalization occurs during design; Localization occurs during development*. I.e.: "Globalization allows Localization".

An example of Globalization is designing a text editor to support right-to-left languages. It isn't tied to one particular language, but it deals with the need to make the application flexible enough to handle such languages.

An example of Localization would be the process of adding the resources to a project for a particular language.

Answer (score 2):

*Globalization*

It is the process of setting up the infrastructure in your code so that your software behaves properly in different cultures/locales.Setting up the infrastructure means:

- No hard-coding of labels anywhere in your software. Designing your software in such a way that you pick the appropriate labels when used in different locales/cultures.
- Coding in such a way that the Date format, Number format changes with culture.
- If you are dealing or displaying time, it should respect the Time zone.

*Localization*

Once the infrastructure is in place, we need to supply appropriate resources for our Globalized software to functional properly in different locales. This process of supplying resources is called localization. For eg:

- Adding of translations for every label used in the software to support different languages.